# Does a functional equation $f : R → R$ include all solutions of $f : N → N$

Tags: functional-equations

If I have a functional equation defined in $f : N → N$ and I have to show that there are no solutions. If I show it for $f : R → R$, does it directly imply there is no solution in $f : N → N$?

Question part 2: even if I would substitute 0 for some variable and the result would show there are no solutions in $f : R → R$, does that mean there are no solutions in $f : N → N$? Seems odd to me

Comment: Yes... of course... because $\mathbb{N} \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Can someone confirm? Seems tirvial, but the problem Im solving seems to easy that way.

Comment: What precisely do you mean by "a functional equation $f: N \to N$"?  $f$ is a function, not a functional equation.

Comment: In the whole text I mean defined in. But thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: But you still didn't say precisely what a functional equation **is**.

Comment: Clearly @Danjel means a *function* that is expressed as an *equation*.

Comment: You should know how to use `\Bbb`/`\mathbb` by now, Danjel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, the "functional equation" $f(x)^2 = \cos(2\pi x)$ has solutions for functions $\mathbb N \to \mathbb N$, but not for $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$.